Shader to make tall grass black and white near player in 3d game for Godot 4
I'd like to add effects to the tall grass near the player in Godot 4.  I think it has something to do with putting all that grass in a layer, than rendering it separately.  I'm currently simply trying to make a shader that turns everything black and white, this video is the closest I've found to instructions:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77F4ZjmQ07U
I don't like that it puts a mesh in front of the camera.  For some reason, it seems like shader processing should happen not as a 3d object in the scene.  I suspect having a mesh in scene will lead to extra transform functions.  I think the solution should involve something that happens after the camera, but I really don't know.

EDIT: Found another video where this person uses a subviewport container, a sub viewport, and then a post-processing node as the child of a camera.  It doesn't seem right to me, because nothing should be the child of the camera unless it's actually just an mod to it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBoApONC7bM

Just to eliminate the obvious, is there any reason you can't just use a custom shader for the grass, inside that shader check the distance between the grass and the camera and the fade to grey scale when close to the camera?

I would like to eventually be able to replace the greyscale with ripple effects or avatar fire-flies or whatever.  More importantly, I don't want to be doing shader work on every entity if the result would be the same for rendering them all first, then doing the shader work second.  I'm as interested in learning the most efficient way as I am getting the result.

This is a "work in progress" answer, but the docs are here:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/screen-reading_shaders.html
For a minimum example, the scene tree should be like this:
Node 3d
 - Camera 3d
   - Mesh Instance 3d


The Mesh3d should be set to Mesh -> Quad.  Set flip faces to checked.  Set height and width to 2m.  Create a material.  Create a new shader material, create a new shader.  In that shader code:
shader_type spatial;
// don't display the quad
render_mode unshaded;

// This is the SCREEN_TEXTURE constant, just with modern syntax.
uniform sampler2D screen_texture: source_color, hint_screen_texture, filter_nearest;

// fill the screen at all times
void vertex() {
    POSITION = vec4(VERTEX, 1.0);
}

// make everything gray
void fragment() {
    vec3 color = texture(screen_texture, SCREEN_UV).rgb;
    float luminance = 0.299 * color.r + 0.587 * color.g + 0.114 * color.b;
    ALBEDO = vec3(luminance);
}



I will continue to modify this answer as I make progress
